# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'. Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm running into android studio emulator incompatible version issues.

> Could not find com.google.android..material:material:1.0.8.

Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.google.android..material:material:1.0.0.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Could not resolve com.google.android..material:material:1.0.0.
> > inconsistent module metadata found. Descriptor: com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0 Errors: bad group: expected='com.google.android..material' found='com.google.android.material'

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps

1. On the left pane, goto Gradle Scripts
2. open file that says build.gradle (Module: *****.app)
3. scroll down you'll find dependencies.
4. Add `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'` inside dependencies
   This should work, if there are any other errors leave a comment.

Comment: Manifest merger failed : Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

Comment: @RecepORTAC what is your minSdkVersion in build.gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the two dots with only one dot after 'android'.
Change this: "com.google.android..material:material:1.0.8"
into this: "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.8"

Comment: Manifest merger failed : Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.